# BootstrapValidator email validate issue

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use BootStrapValidator.js for form validation in ASP MVC but i dosen't validate email regex cause MVC return input name="Email" that validator work on name = "email" when i edit input box name attribute to "email" it work fine.`@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email, new { placeholder = "sample@domain.com", @class = "form-control", id = "Email",type="email" })`
 
inspector result

```
<input class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="sample@domain.com" value="" name="Email" type="email">
```

No different if i add name="email" to @html helper it change it to "Email"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change `@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email, new { placeholder = "sample@domain.com", @class = "form-control", id = "Email",type="email" })` to `@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email, new { placeholder = "sample@domain.com", @class = "form-control", id = "Email",type="email",@Name= "email" })`
It fixed.